# Is there a way to exit a case in a switch on a conditional?

Tags: javascript, code.org

I have code which deals with an event listener, and I need the code to pause and wait for the event before continuing execution.  However, this code is run inside of a switch() statement.  Is there a way to do something like this to exit the case?
`case(number): if(value){break;}`
This is being done in code.org by the way.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. It's valid syntax

Comment: *"I need the code to pause and wait for the event before continuing execution"*: I don't think you really want that. It would block the user interface. Use standard event handling. Attach a listener and handle it.

Comment: Can you put some more code, qus is not clear

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. An event handler should only be called after the event happens. Therefore it is unclear what you want to wait for.

Answer (score -1):

A break will allow you continue processing in the function. Just returning out of the switch is fine if that's all you want to do in the function.